# Ubuntu requirements on Dell XPS T500

Tags: dell, system-requirements

Could I install Ubuntu on a Dell XPS T500 witha 500 mhz cpu and 1128 mb of ram installed???
My friend and I are using it to run a website server. Great thanks to anyone who responds!

Comment: It is 128 MB or 1128 MB? I've never seen a machine with 1128 MB, since RAM sticks aren;'t made in that denomination.

Comment: Either it's a spello, or he just mentioned the amount it shows in the system - Oh well, 1128 is weird!